# creating n nested loops from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have a dictionary which has n keys, each key contains a list of n strings.

I want to iterate across every combination of string yielding the key and the string associated with it.

This is an example of a dictionary with 3 keys but I want to generalise to a dictionary with n keys.

```
dict = {'key1':['str0','str1','str2','strn'],'key2':['apples','bananas','mangos'],'key3':['spam','eggs','more spam']}

for str1 in dict['key1']:
    for str2 in dict['key2']:
        for str3 in dict['key3']:
            print 'key1'+"."+str1,'key2'+"."+str2,'key3'+"."+str3
```

Please when answering the question could you describe how the answer works as I'm reasonably new to python and don't know all of the tools available yet!

Expected output:

```
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.spam
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.eggs
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.more spam
key1.str0 key2.bananas key3.spam
key1.str0 key2.bananas key3.eggs
...
```

Expected output for an n-dimensional iterator:

```
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.spam ... keyn.string0
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.spam ... keyn.string1
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.spam ... keyn.string2
...
key1.str0 key2.apples key3.spam ... keyn.stringn
...
```

Comment: Can you please include the expected output?

Comment: He/she wants it generalized to n keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which performs a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), which is the name of the thing you are trying to do.

```
from itertools import product

# don't shadow the built-in name `dict`
d = {'key1': ['str0','str1','str2','strn'], 'key2': ['apples','bananas','mangos'], 'key3': ['spam','eggs','more spam']}

# dicts aren't sorted, but you seem to want key1 -> key2 -> key3 order, so 
# let's get a sorted copy of the keys
keys = sorted(d.keys())
# and then get the values in the same order
values = [d[key] for key in keys]

# perform the Cartesian product
# product(*values) means product(values[0], values[1], values[2], ...)
results = product(*values)

# each `result` is something like ('str0', 'apples', 'spam')
for result in results:
    # pair up each entry in `result` with its corresponding key
    # So, zip(('key1', 'key2', 'key3'), ('str0', 'apples', 'spam'))
    # yields (('key1', 'str0'), ('key2', 'apples'), ('key3', 'spam'))
    # schematically speaking, anyway
    for key, thing in zip(keys, result):
        print key + '.' + thing, 
    print
```

Notice that nowhere have we hardcoded the number of keys in the dictionary. You could avoid the sorting stuff if you use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of a `dict`.

---

Here is another option if you want the keys attached to their values:

```
from itertools import product

d = {'key1': ['str0','str1','str2','strn'], 'key2': ['apples','bananas','mangos'], 'key3': ['spam','eggs','more spam']}

foo = [[(key, value) for value in d[key]] for key in sorted(d.keys())]

results = product(*foo)
for result in results:
    for key, value in result:
        print key + '.' + value,
    print
```

Here, we construct a list of lists of (key, value) tuples, and then apply the Cartesian product to the lists. This way, the relationship between keys and values is entirely containe in `results`. Come to think of it, this is probably better than the first way I posted.

Comment: I like this solution but is there any way to make it more elegant as currently the keys must stay in the same order between `results = product(*values)` and the for loop. Is there anyway to link `keys` and `result` other than just `zip(keys,result)`

Comment: @alexmcf See my edit (below the line). Yes - you can take the product over lists of (key, value) tuples rather than lists of values. This is probably better than the way I initially posted.

Comment: just a note to anyone using this in the future... It will fail if you have any empty lists within the dict

Comment: @alexmcf It's true that you won't get any output if there are any empty lists in the dict. What output were you expecting?

Comment: It's a rather specific issue in which I was using empty lists to signify I needed to call to an API to fill them with every possible value rather than hardcoded pre-defined values. Code works great and I now know how to apply cartesian products outside a physics exam lol

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function:

```
# make a list of all the keys
keys = list(dict.keys())

def f(keys, dict, depth=0, to_print=[]):
    if depth < len(keys):
        for item in dict[keys[depth]]:
            to_print.append(keys[depth] + '.' + item + ' ')
            f(keys, dict, depth + 1, to_print)
            del to_print[-1]
    else:
        # you can format the output as you wish; here i'm just printing the list
        print to_print


# call the function
f(keys, dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem but I didn't just want to print out a long list, I wanted to do other things with the variables so having the iterator hidden in a function makes it a less portable solution

Comment: Ok. You can still do other things with the variables in the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

I was going for a more functional style, it is basically the same as @Senshin's answer:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint
def foo(d):
    def g(item):
        """create and return key.value1, key.value2, ..., key.valueN iterator

        item is a (key, value) dictionary item, assumes value is a sequence/iterator
        """
        # associate the key with each value - (key, value0) ... (key, valueN)
        kay_vees = itertools.izip(itertools.repeat(item[0]), item[1])
        return itertools.imap('.'.join, kay_vees)

    # generator that produces n data sets from the dict
    a = itertools.imap(g, d.iteritems())

    # cartesian product of the datasets
    return itertools.product(*a)
```

Usage:

```
c = list(foo(d))
pprint(c)

for thing in foo(d):
    print thing
```

Once consumed, iterators need to be *redefined* - `foo` will return a new iterator for each call.